# Log into a website with VBA or Python (?), extract a file then auto format it with a macro on excel

Tags: python, vba, excel

I would like to have access to a template already saved on the platform online (through my ID obviously) and export it through a python or VBA, **which one should I use?**

With VBA I found something like this online :

```
Sub test()
' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "mywebsite"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

' Input the userid and password
    ie.Document.getElementById("uid").Value = "testID"
    ie.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "testPW"

' Click the "Search" button
    ie.Document.getElementById("enter").Click

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

My first problem is that, I have to **select on a drop down menu** my namespace that we would call here namespacetest, compulsory to get to the authentication section (same URL) it's java. So this part of code is a start.

Then I get to my page, I want to **access to a folder, access to the right template** (without unique URL) **and export it** as I would do manually by selecting the right option on the UI window of Orion.

I will edit this post to make it clearer after the first suggestion or guidance I will receive, because it may be a bit unclear !